# Access app with sign in?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office, excel-2013

good day to all. I just had a general question here and hope someone is available to help.

I have a database for employees and was wondering if I could make an app or program in Access or Excel where I can assign each employee a username and password so when they log in they can print out an employment letter for example.

Basically I have the list of employees and the templates of the letters and all and well its just a matter of checking the possibilities and how to go about doing this and with which office product.

Thanks,

Will

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, do you have a link or any idea where I can see examples or where I can go to get a good start to this?

Comment: Do you want to restrict access to the App, or just force users to log into one part of the App? If you Google the words "sample access form for login" you will get more ideas than you can imagine.

Comment: Well here is my idea. I have about 20 different letters for two countries, US and Brazil. I want to give the employees their log in credentials and have them pick from a list, the kind of letter they want. Then, somehow from the selection, Access will look for the employee in a spreadsheet in Excel or maybe even in Access fetch the information and put it in a letter that I have in a Word document. Does it sound possible at all? or Am I just like way off here with what I would like to do?

Comment: Oh @WayneG.Dunn thanks for the reply and I am looking up what you said as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, since you have a choice, I would use Access instead of Excel.

1. Create your table of users; populate it.
2. Create your Form; add controls for sign-in; add ComboBox for "Letter Type"; add command button to "Submit"
3. Is the letter going to be customized for the user (their name, address, etc.?) or just a standard form letter? If customized, you will need to create a "Mail Merge" Word document and pass the variables to it (i.e. use VBA code in the "Submit" button) Lots of resources for this if you Google "Access Word Mail Merge VBA"
4. How will the letter be sent? Email? If so, there is VBA for that also.
   Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks Wayne for the time and the input... there lots of work to be done on this so please look for more questions in the near future... There is a standard format for the letters and only certain fields on the letter will be populated depending on the employees information and the letter will be emailed to the corresponding department for validation, and signature.